# Pip2.7 tries to find package from Python 3 Libraries

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install gym library using pip2.7 but it complains that the library is installed in python 3.5 folders.

```
pip2 install gym
```

Result:

```
Requirement already satisfied: gym in /home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from gym)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0 in /home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from gym)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in /home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from gym)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet>=1.2.0 in /home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from gym)
```

Why is it like that ?

`python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` gives

`['', '/home/alex/naoqi/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-linux64', '/home/alex/naoqi/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.2.17-linux64', '/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python35.zip', '/home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5', '/home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', '/home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.6-py3.5.egg', '/home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg']`

Comment: Is `PYTHONPATH` set in your environment, by chance?

Comment: Yes and ```echo  $PYTHONPATH``` gives ```/home/alex/naoqi/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-linux64:/home/alex/naoqi/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.2.17-linux64:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages``` Although it might be irrelevent to the problem, I am running ```pip2 install gym``` in a conda environment.

Comment: Hmm. No smoking gun there. What does `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` output?

Comment: The result is too long and I pasted in the original question. Does this affect the behavior of pip2 ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure (which is why I decided to comment rather than post an 'answer'), but it seems plausible. Perhaps you could try temporarily moving `/home/alex/anaconda2/envs/gym` and re-run `pip2 install gym`. If it works, I guess that's strong evidence that the `sys.path` contents are affecting `pip2`. (The next step would then be to figure out *why* `sys.path` contains what it does.)